# Unable to use another layout element in another activity - android studio

Tags: java, android, xml

I've 3 activities in my android game: `MainActivity`, `OptionActivity` and `GameActivity`. I'm trying to pull in elements of `board_view.xml` into another activity, i.e., into `OptionActivity.java`.
`board_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cell11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cell10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cell11"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cell11"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cell11" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cell12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cell11"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cell11"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cell11" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cell01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/cell12"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cell11" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cell21"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cell11"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cell11" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cell00"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cell01"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cell01"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cell10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cell02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cell01"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cell12" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cell20"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cell21"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cell21"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/cell10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cell22"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/cell21"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cell21"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/cell12" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm using this code to pull elements from `board_view.xml` into `OptionActivity.java`:

```
Button tiles[][];

    public Button[][] getTiles() {
        tiles[0][0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cell00);
        tiles[0][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cell01);
        tiles[0][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cell02);
        tiles[1][0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cell10);
        tiles[1][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cell11);
        tiles[1][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cell12);
        tiles[2][0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cell20);
        tiles[2][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cell21);
        tiles[2][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cell22);
        return tiles;
    }
```

And I'm using those tiles in spinner click events as given below:

```
private void spinnerListener() {
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String s = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("easy")) {
                    tiles[0][0].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(0, 0);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[0][1].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(0, 1);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[0][2].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(0, 2);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[1][0].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(1, 0);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[1][1].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(1, 1);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[1][2].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(1, 2);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[2][0].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(2, 0);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[2][1].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(2, 1);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[2][2].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(2, 2);
                        }
                    });
                } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("intermediate")) {
                    tiles[0][0].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(0, 1);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[0][1].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(0, 0);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[0][2].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(0, 2);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[1][0].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(1, 1);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[1][1].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(1, 0);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[1][2].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(1, 2);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[2][0].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(2, 1);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[2][1].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(2, 0);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[2][2].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(2, 2);
                        }
                    });
                } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("difficult")) {
                    Toast.makeText(OptionActivity.this, "Difficult", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                Toast.makeText(OptionActivity.this, "Please select the difficulty level!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

But when `OptionActivity` is loaded in mobile, I get this error:

```
02-22 00:47:13.369 8383-8383/com.example.ajaykulkarni.tictactoe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.example.ajaykulkarni.tictactoe, PID: 8383
                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
                                                                                      at com.example.ajaykulkarni.tictactoe.OptionActivity$1.onItemSelected(OptionActivity.java:106)
                                                                                      at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:931)
                                                                                      at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:920)
                                                                                      at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300(AdapterView.java:55)
                                                                                      at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:890)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5621)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
```

How can I pull array of buttons from another layout to another activity?
**`EDIT:`**
`OptionActivity:`

```
public class OptionActivity extends Activity implements Observer {

    Model model;
    Button start_game;
    Button one_player;
    RadioGroup group;
    RadioButton player1_turn;
    RadioButton player2_turn;
    EditText player1_name;
    EditText player2_name;
    Spinner spinner1;
    Button tiles[][];

    public Button[][] getTiles() {
        tiles[0][0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cell00);
        tiles[0][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cell01);
        tiles[0][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cell02);
        tiles[1][0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cell10);
        tiles[1][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cell11);
        tiles[1][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cell12);
        tiles[2][0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cell20);
        tiles[2][1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cell21);
        tiles[2][2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cell22);
        return tiles;
    }

    public Model getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /*setContentView(R.layout.activity_option);*/
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_option);
        setTitle("Tic-Tac-Toe");
        Log.d("Tic-Tac-Toe", "Game Option constructor");

        // setup the model
        model = new Model();
        model.addObserver(this);

        // setup the radio buttons and radio group
        group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.select_turn);

        player1_turn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.player1_turn);
        player2_turn = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.player2_turn);

        // setup the edit texts
        player1_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player1_name);
        player2_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player2_name);

        // setup the game mode buttons
        one_player = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one_player);

        // register the controller
        this.registerController();

        /*spinner functionalities*/
        this.addSpinner();
        this.spinnerListener();

    }

    private void addSpinner() {
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, R.id.spinner1);
        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    }

    private void spinnerListener() {
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String s = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("easy")) {
                    tiles[0][0].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(0, 0);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[0][1].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(0, 1);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[0][2].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(0, 2);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[1][0].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(1, 0);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[1][1].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(1, 1);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[1][2].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(1, 2);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[2][0].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(2, 0);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[2][1].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(2, 1);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[2][2].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(2, 2);
                        }
                    });
                } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("intermediate")) {
                    tiles[0][0].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(0, 1);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[0][1].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(0, 0);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[0][2].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(0, 2);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[1][0].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(1, 1);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[1][1].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(1, 0);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[1][2].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(1, 2);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[2][0].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(2, 1);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[2][1].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(2, 0);
                        }
                    });

                    tiles[2][2].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            model.playerMove(2, 2);
                        }
                    });
                } else if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("difficult")) {
                    Toast.makeText(OptionActivity.this, "Difficult", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                Toast.makeText(OptionActivity.this, "Please select the difficulty level!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

`BoardView.java:`

```
public class BoardView extends RelativeLayout implements Observer {

    Model model;
    Button tiles[][];

    public BoardView(Context context, Model m) {
        super(context);

        Log.d("Tic-Tac-Toe", "BoardView constructor");
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.board_view, this);

        // save the model reference
        model = m;
        // add this view to model's list of observers
        model.addObserver(this);

        // get a reference to widgets to manipulate on update
        tiles = new Button[3][3];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                String row = Integer.toString(i);
                String col = Integer.toString(j);
                String tileId = "cell" + row + col;
                int id = getResources().getIdentifier(tileId, "id",
                        getContext().getPackageName());
                tiles[i][j] = (Button) findViewById(id);
                tiles[i][j].setFocusable(false);
                tiles[i][j].getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.WHITE,
                        PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            }
        }

        this.registerControllers();
    }

    /* the controller part */
    private void registerControllers() {
        tiles[0][0].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                model.playerMove(0, 0);
            }
        });

        tiles[0][1].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                model.playerMove(0, 1);
            }
        });

        tiles[0][2].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                model.playerMove(0, 2);
            }
        });

        tiles[1][0].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                model.playerMove(1, 0);
            }
        });

        tiles[1][1].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                model.playerMove(1, 1);
            }
        });

        tiles[1][2].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                model.playerMove(1, 2);
            }
        });

        tiles[2][0].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                model.playerMove(2, 0);
            }
        });

        tiles[2][1].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                model.playerMove(2, 1);
            }
        });

        tiles[2][2].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                model.playerMove(2, 2);
            }
        });
    }
```

The line `OptionActivity.java:106` is:

```
tiles[0][0].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

Comment: Please show a complete example. We both Activity classes. Note this does not mean to post all of your code. You only need to show the code relevant to your question. In particular, show a basic `onCreate()` method for each class and show how each activity is started.

Comment: In addition, note that the error message has `OptionActivity.java:106`. This means the error occurs on line 106 of OptionActivity.java. Please tell us which line this is.

Comment: You can't access views of one activity in another.  They don't exist in the other activity.  What you can do is include the same views in the layout via either an include, a fragment, or a custom view.  But they won't be the same views as in the previous Activity.

Comment: You should consider simplifying your code with a for loop and a named OnClickListener. With a named class, you can add a constructor in order to parameterize the small differences between your current anonymous classes.

Comment: Why not using a Fragment, with its own ContentView, which you could use in both Activities?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: please check my edited question

Comment: I assume you mean your edited **question**. See my answer, along with the edit which addresses your edits.

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo... Thank you, I'll check that out

Comment: I am a little bit confused. You mention "another activity" in your question, but I only see one activity named `OptionActivity`. Perhaps you are referring to the custom view named `BoardView`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: yeah, you are correct. There is a custom view named `BoardView`, I'm trying to use that in another activity named as `optionActivity`

Comment: I'm still confused. In your recent comment you still mention "another activity". The word "another" implies you have a first activity. However, the code you show here only has a single activity. What is the first activity?

Comment: Another way to clarify my question is to show `activity_option.xml`. Does this have a `<com.your.package.BoardView>` tag? If not, which XML file and activity does have this?

Comment: My `activity_option.xml` has `com.example.ajaykulkarni.tictactoe.OptionActivity`. There is no reference to `BoardView`

Comment: You should not put an activity tag in a layout. In fact, I am very surprised there are no compiler errors. Very likely, the tag is simply ignored. Can you please show the XML layout for `OptionActivity` as well as the layout which contains `com.example.ajaykulkarni.tictactoe.BoardView`?

Comment: p.s. You should learn about `GridLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate problem and cause of the error message is that you never initialize your array in `OptionActivity`:

```
Button tiles[][];
```

Even though you mention "another activity" in your question, it appears that you have a custom view `BoardView` and a single activity `OptionActivity`. The `Activity` should treat `BoardView` as a single, complete entity and never access its internal components directly, including individual subviews. Instead, `BoardView` should provide appropriate methods allow very controlled interaction. If you do this correctly, an activity will have only a single `findViewById()` call to get the `BoardView` from the layout.

**Recap of comments**

`OptionActivity` should not be aware of `BoardView` not its internal workings. Instead it should only be responsible for setting preferences and saving them. Most likely you should use [`SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) for this. Using [`PreferenceActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) will help tremendously.

Now your `MainActivity` will load the options from `SharedPreferences` and pass them to `BoardView`. The "appropriate methods" I mentioned earlier will be one or more setter methods.

> `BoardView` contains the code for game operations and is influenced by the options that is selected in `OptionActivity`.

Note that, with my suggestion, `BoardView` is influenced by the **values** of the options but not by where those values come from. This provides a lot of flexibility. Also, `OptionActivity` is not influenced by `BoardView` at all, at least not directly.

If there are a lot of options you should consider grouping related ones into one or more class.

Comment: Okay, can you give me some examples of appropriate methods to interact with subviews?

Comment: @AjayKulkarni What information will the activity need from the `BoardView`? What actions does the activity need to tell the `BoardView` to perform? You are likely already doing these things in `OptionActivity` when you should do them in `BoardView` instead.

Comment: I got an idea, maybe I can move that custom spinner in `activity_option.xml` to `board_view.xml` and define spinner element click operations in `BoardView.java` which would avoid all these issues...

Comment: @AjayKulkarni That does not sound like a very good solution. What is the purpose of the spinner?

Comment: I'm using spinner to select the game's difficulty levels. There are 3 difficulty levels: `Easy`, `Intermediate` and `Difficult`

Comment: @AjayKulkarni It seems to me that you need to simply save your options in the `OptionActivity`. Persumably you also have a `MainActivity` or whatever name you use. `MainActivity` should then load the options and use them appropriately. `OptionActivity` should not access `BoardView` at all, or even know that it exists.

Comment: Well, that'd not be so optimal. `BoardView` contains the code for game operations and is influenced by the options that is selected in `OptionActivity`.

Comment: @AjayKulkarni exactly. So MainActivity loads the options which have previously been saved by OptionActivity (using SharedPreferences, perhaps) then passes the options to BoardView. This completely decouples the classes as much as possible and separates concerns. It also encapsulates data in BoardView which should not be available outside that class.

Comment: @AjayKulkarni I edited my answer to restate my comment and expand on it.